# Something like "padding box" to modify DIV, different 100% values of its content?

Tags: css, padding, indentation, box

I'm trying to achieve some indent for content inside div. I want to have all elements inside to have 100% width, but first ones have to be positioned further from the left side. This demonstration shows what I exactly need:

[image]

I tried to mess around with ::before pseudoelement for parent div, different positioning and floating but no luck. Is there a way to achieve this in CSS or maybe jQuery?

Comment: what you tried sofar? create a fiddle demo with that code, so that we can help further

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use  the [`:nth-child` pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) to select the items you want and then just give them a [`margin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/margin).

```css
div{
    border:1px solid #000;
    padding:5px 10px;
}
p{
  background:#000;
  font-family:arial;
  color:#fff;
  margin:5px 0;
  padding:5px;
}
p:nth-child(-n+2){
  margin:5px 0 5px 50px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <p>First</p>
    <p>Second</p>
    <p>Third</p>
    <p>Fourth</p>
</div>
```

By the way, floating items and giving them a 100% `width` is somewhat redundant so I have omitted that from my code.

Comment: Thank you for `:nth-child()` selector!!

Comment: You're welcome. I've updated my answer to include a link to the MDN article on `:nth-child`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add `width:100%` to your elements. If they are block elements it will take automatically 100% of the container width. Then just use `margin`to whatever element you need:
HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content margin"></div>
    <div class="content margin"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {margin:0; padding:0;}
.container {
    width:400px;
    padding:20px;
    background-color:#ddd;
}
.content {
    height:60px;
    background-color:green;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    position:relative;
}
.margin {
    margin-left:150px;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/eyyuheaa/2/)**